# Meu site é feito de imagens animadas com javascript. Como torna-lo responsivo?

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout-responsivo, slide

Antes de tudo: comecei a programar não faz nem uma semana, estou bem interessado a aprender, então enquanto espero a resposta vou estar me **esforçando** pra me virar, mas, uma ajuda não seria nada mal :)

Como a ideia do site era parecer uma animaçãozinha, utilizei de slides **javascript** pra fazer as imagens do site ficarem alternando entre 3-2 frames

Bem, nessa parte ele já tem um menuzinho basico, **PORÉM** só fica bonitinho assim no meu browser com 100% de zoom, se eu diminuo o zoom tudo se distancia e fica em cima do outro, todo desfigurado, como na imagem 2.

No celular não tá tão ruim, me parece mais simples até...

```js
addEventListener("load", () => { // "load" is safe but "DOMContentLoaded" starts earlier
  var index = 0;
  const slides = document.querySelectorAll(".slides");
  const classHide = "slides-hidden",
    count = slides.length;
  nextSlide();

  function nextSlide() {
    slides[(index++) % count].classList.add(classHide);
    slides[index % count].classList.remove(classHide);
    setTimeout(nextSlide, 500);
  }
});


addEventListener("load", () => { // "load" is safe but "DOMContentLoaded" starts earlier
  var index = 0;
  const slides = document.querySelectorAll(".slidez");
  const classHide = "slides-hiddez",
    count = slides.length;
  nextSlide();

  function nextSlide() {
    slides[(index++) % count].classList.add(classHide);
    slides[index % count].classList.remove(classHide);
    setTimeout(nextSlide, 250);
  }
});

addEventListener("load", () => { // "load" is safe but "DOMContentLoaded" starts earlier
  var index = 0;
  const slides = document.querySelectorAll(".slidex");
  const classHide = "slides-hiddex",
    count = slides.length;
  nextSlide();

  function nextSlide() {
    slides[(index++) % count].classList.add(classHide);
    slides[index % count].classList.remove(classHide);
    setTimeout(nextSlide, 350);
  }
});

addEventListener("load", () => { // "load" is safe but "DOMContentLoaded" starts earlier
  var index = 0;
  const slides = document.querySelectorAll(".slidey");
  const classHide = "slides-hiddey",
    count = slides.length;
  nextSlide();

  function nextSlide() {
    slides[(index++) % count].classList.add(classHide);
    slides[index % count].classList.remove(classHide);
    setTimeout(nextSlide, 450);
  }
});
```

```css
.slides {
  width: 70%;
}

.slides-hidden {
  display: none;
}

.slidez {
  width: 25%;
}

.slides-hiddez {
  display: none;
}

.slidex {
  width: 25%;
}

.slides-hiddex {
  display: none;
}

.slidey {
  width: 25%;
}

.slides-hiddey {
  display: none;
}

.spotify {
  position: absolute;
  top: 400px;
  left: 830px;
}

.youtube {
  position: absolute;
  top: 400px;
  left: 620px;
}

.instagram {
  position: absolute;
  top: 400px;
  left: 405px;
}

.strainberry-logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 190px;
  left: 300px;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: ubuntu;
  src: url('ubuntu.otf');
}

body {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-family: ubuntu;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>

  <div class="strainberry-logo">

    <img class="slides slides-hidden" src="https://i.ibb.co/Ny1H4vM/stb1.png" draggable="false">
    <img class="slides slides-hidden" src="https://i.ibb.co/rpVXy8L/stb2.png" draggable="false">
    <img class="slides slides-hidden" src="https://i.ibb.co/YdR80My/stb3.png" draggable="false">

  </div>

  <div class="instagram">

    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/strainberryrec" target="_blank">
      <img class="slidez slides-hiddez" src="http://www.strainberry.com/instagram01.png" draggable="false">
      <img class="slidez slides-hiddez" src="http://www.strainberry.com/instagram02.png" draggable="false">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="youtube">

    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCrweqpJMG6a6I-DYO4rUBZw" target="_blank">
      <img class="slidex slides-hiddex" src="http://www.strainberry.com/youtube01.png" draggable="false">
      <img class="slidex slides-hiddex" src="http://www.strainberry.com/youtube02.png" draggable="false">
    </a>

  </div>

  <div class="spotify">

    <a href="https://open.spotify.com/artist/0WLWFwflNKbZT0fR4442oB?si=Qm2sEQUaQGyn0zgsA7sZww&dl_branch=1" target="_blank">
      <img class="slidey slides-hiddey" src="http://www.strainberry.com/spotify01.png" draggable="false">
      <img class="slidey slides-hiddey" src="http://www.strainberry.com/spotify02.png" draggable="false">
    </a>

  </div>

</body>


</html>
```

[image: Como o site é pra ser]
[image: Como fica com um zoom menor]
[image: Como fica em um celular]

**EDIT: Já consegui fazer uma espécie de responsividade, inclusive no [site mobile](http://www.strainberry.com) com media queries. Ainda está incompleto mas já tenho uma guia. O problema é que o complicamento do zoom ainda continua.**

Answer (score -2):

Para conseguir a responsividade vc está no caminho certo, dentro do css crie um:

```
@media (max-width: ***) and (min-width: ***){


//Aqui virá o código css que será mostrado na página pras especificações a cima.


}
```

Você pode ir atras de um conteudo chamado BreakPoints que faz marcação de altura e comprimento usado para varios celulares e computadores que vai te dar uma noção de qual width e heigth usar.

Agr depois de criar um @media pra cada BreakPoints.

Sabendo disso, basta usando width,heigth,max-width,max-heigth,border-box e flex dentro do css que vc ja consegue tornar o site responsivo.